# How to send FormData containing json and file in React?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, http, postman, multipartform-data

I am using React in the frontend and Spring boot in the backend. I am trying to send a request that contains an image, as well as some json data by using the FormData in React.

**This is my current code in the frontend:**

```
const submitForm = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

   const swimArea = "{\"swimArea\" : {\"name\": \"aTESTTEST\", \"longitude\": \"15.47\",    \"latitude\": \"56.25\"}}";
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('swimArea', JSON.stringify(swimArea));
   formData.append("file", e.target.file);

   const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=----somefixedboundary`,
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
      },
      body: formData,
   };
   fetch(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bathplace/newBathingPlace",
      requestOptions
   )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {  // Continue with the data...
      });
};
```

**This is how the Spring API looks like:**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/newBathingPlace")
public ResponseObject addBathingPlace(@RequestPart AddBathingPlaceRequest swimArea, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
   // Handling the request...
   return new ResponseObject();
}
```

I have tested the API with Postman and it works:
[FormData in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl7IE.png)
[Request headers for the FormData in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4unB.png)

Now to the problem, in the browser I get this error:
*"message": "Required request part 'swimArea' is not present"*

I believe something is missing or wrong with the react-code, but not sure what. If you know anything please point me in the right direction.
I have tried removing the file-implementation from both server and client. Get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it to work... I've been stuck on this problem for weeks, and hours after I post the question here, I solve it, sigh.

The issue was how I created the formdata, this is the new code for that part:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const blob = new Blob([e.target.file.files[0]], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
formData.append('swimArea', new Blob([JSON.stringify(swimArea)], { type: "application/json" }));
formData.append("file", blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

just change  `formData.append("file", e.target.file);` to  `formData.append("file", e.currentTarget.files.[0])`

Comment: The file-part is not what is causing the problem... even if I remove formData.append("file", e.target.file); I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the `FormData()` constructor is not used properly. You are stringifying the swimArea object twice. You have already stringified it when you created the object as

```
const swimArea = "{\"swimArea\" : {\"name\": \"aTESTTEST\", \"longitude\":
\"15.47\",\"latitude\": \"56.25\"}}";
```

, yet you are stringifying again at

`formData.append('swimArea', JSON.stringify(swimArea));`

You can try the following.

```
const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const swimArea = {
        swimArea: {
            name: "aTESTTEST",
            longitude: "15.47",
            latitude: "56.25"
        }
    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('swimArea', JSON.stringify(swimArea));
    formData.append('file', e.target.files[0])

   const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=----somefixedboundary`,
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
      },
      body: formData,
   };
   fetch(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bathplace/newBathingPlace",
      requestOptions
   )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {  // Continue with the data...
      });
};
```

Also. when working with `FormData`, the browser automatically sets the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` with the correct boundary. Manually setting this header can cause issues.